# Como guardar elementos de un ciclo FOR en un archivo de texto

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

estoy aprendiendo python actualmente y estoy trabajando con el modulo requests para manipular la API  de MercadoLibre. Lo que he hecho es obtener una lista de categorias por medio de un get  y luego imprimirlas todas en consola lo cual me ha funcionado de la siguiente manera.

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get('https://api.mercadolibre.com/categories/MLM1748')
dta = r.json()
for element in dta['children_categories']:
  ide = element['id']
  name = element['name']
  links = 'https://api.mercadolibre.com/categories/'+ide
  print(links)
```

Mi pregunta hasta aqui es, como puedo guardar todos los links que obtengo en un archivo de texto? Espero que alguien puedo brindarme ayuda gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los enfoques típicos son:

1. Tienes un bucle que recoge los datos (el tuyo serviría) y los va guardando en una lista en lugar de imprimirlos, y al final del bucle vuelcas la lista en disco.
2. Abres un fichero antes de entrar al bucle y en cada iteración, vuelcas al fichero en lugar de (o además de) la pantalla.

### Primer enfoque

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get('https://api.mercadolibre.com/categories/MLM1748')
dta = r.json()
lista = []
for element in dta['children_categories']:
  ide = element['id']
  name = element['name']
  links = 'https://api.mercadolibre.com/categories/'+ide
  lista.append(links)

with open("resultado.txt", "w") as f:
  for elemento in lista:
     f.write(elemento)
     f.write("\n")    # Si quieres líneas separadas
```

### Segundo enfoque

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get('https://api.mercadolibre.com/categories/MLM1748')
dta = r.json()
with open("resultado.txt", "w") as f:
    for element in dta['children_categories']:
      ide = element['id']
      name = element['name']
      links = 'https://api.mercadolibre.com/categories/'+ide
      print(links, file=f)
```

En ambos enfoques usé *contextos* que son bloques que comienzan por `with` que pueden usarse con algunos tipos de datos. En el caso de los ficheros los contextos son útiles porque cuando se finaliza el bloque del contexto, automáticamente se cierra el fichero, así no se te olvidará nunca cerrarlo.

En cuanto a la forma de escribir en disco, en el primer ejemplo usé `f.write()`, que no añade automáticamente retornos de carro por lo que tengo que añadirlo después con otro `f.write()`. En el segundo caso usé `print()` con el argumento `file=`. Cualquiera de las dos formas es válida, elige la que más te guste.

Comment: Muchas gracias ya lo he solucionado, el otro problema que tenia era que solo me registraba el ultimo link pero he cambiado 'w' por 'a' y listo ya me guarda todos muchas gracias :D

Answer (score 1):

Usa las funciones de manipulación de archivos de python

```
file = open("links.txt","w")
file.write(links)
file.close()
```

[Open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacelo asi:

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get('https://api.mercadolibre.com/categories/MLM1748')
dta = r.json()
with open("file.txt","w") as f: # abrimos el archivo en modo escritura y le pones f como alias

    for element in dta['children_categories']:
      ide = element['id']
      name = element['name']
      links = 'https://api.mercadolibre.com/categories/'+ide
      f.write(links) #escribimos los links en el archivo
      print(links)

    f.close() # cerramos el archivo
```